# Single phase double pole cap. start motor siezes up

Tags: induction-motor

Power off- motor freewheels
Power on- motor runs for a few minutes then siezes up.
Power off immediately-  Motor freewheels.

Is the capacitor shorting out internally from heat?  How can I check for this, continuity from terminal to case AFTER discharging, maybe?

Comment: Put a 100 W incandescent lamp in series with the cap. If it goes full brightness you know the cap has short-circuited. Report back. Clarify what "siezes up" means.

Comment: If it is a capacitor-start motor, the capacitor should be out of the circuit in about 1 second. It seems more likely that there is a mechanical problem like the rotor moving axially. If the rotor is not quite centered axially in the stator, there could be a force toward one end or the other. That doesn't quite explain why it takes a few minutes to move and then completely frees up when power is shut off. The centrifugal switch may be involved in the mechanical interference. Check to see if the motor can be moved axially by hand.

Comment: Perhaps the capacitor is being switched back into the circuit a few minutes after starting. Is the power shut off immediately by a circuit breaker tripping or manually.